# Using Prospects Theory in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

:I have problems when I use the Prospects theorem into my merges pricing model. so, I want to ask for you help.
Q1: I don't know how to define the relative change in merges price if we used the Prospects theory.

Q2: This paper"PRICING MERGERS & ACQUISITIONS USING AGENT-BASED MODELING" inspires me a lot. But It's difficult to come true in Netlogo , If you have the some interesting in the Pricing of merges using Prospects theory, Please contacts me, and help together. thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about fixing a piece of code

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a suitable question for StackOverflow. The purpose is to help you with problems fixing a specific piece of code. That is, you need to have some draft code that doesn't do what you want it to do and a description of what you want it to do. Instead, you are asking for someone to work with you to design and then build a model.